# Rails replace text_field from _form by text_field from edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm super fresh with Rails views

I've made rails app by `rails new scaffold` where inside of `_form.html.erb` was below code:

```
<%= form_with(model: property, local: true) do |form| %>

(...)

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :status %>
    <%= form.text_field :status %>
  </div>

(...)
```

Because I need to have default value for `:status` inside of `new.html.erb` I've modified `_form.html.erb`

```
    <%= form.label :status %>
    <%= form.text_field :status, value: 'planned', readonly: true  %>
```

Which has the effect of `edit.html.erb` where I rendered `_form.html.erb` because I need all the other fields from `_form`.

`edit.html.erb`

```
<h1>Editing Property</h1>

<%= render 'form', property: @property %>

<%= link_to 'Show', @property %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', properties_path %>
```

Is there a way to replace only this `form.text_field :status` from `_form` inside of `edit.html.erb` and the other fields leave like it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve it by passing extra params to `_form.html.erb`:

```rb
# new.html.erb
<%= render 'form', extra_params: {value: 'planned', readonly: true} %>

# _form.html.erb
<%= form.text_field :status, local_assigns[:extra_params] || {}  %>
```

Or just in `_form.html.erb`:

```rb
# _form.html.erb
<% extra_params = @property&.persisted? ? {} : {value: 'planned', readonly: true} %>

<%= form.text_field :status, extra_params %>
```